# Which bower package do I need in order to work with locationProvider in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, bower-install

I am trying to remove the hash tag from the url in angularJS. From the research I found that I need to use `$locationProvider` but I can not figure out which dependency is required to get this working!

This is my angular code

```
angular.module('airlineApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
]).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/testing', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

That does not work, I'm assuming it's because I don't have `locationProvider`.

I am using the angular engine in bower to help with dependency instalments. So for `locationProvider` I tried

```
bower install --save locationProvider
```

That doesn't exist, I also search in the bower Search Bower Packages section and can't find anything useful.

I'm just starting with angular so it might be that the problem is elsewhere. Do you know what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$locationProvider must work from box

try use another for for injector

```
angular.module('airlineApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/testing', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

if possible - give a value that got your module by name $locationProvider or show exxample at jsbin

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you getting an specific error message on console?

2) Be sure to include the .js files, like

```
<script src="bower_components/locationProvider"></script>
```

Comment: This is the problem, I don't have that js file. That is the component I don't have and I can't fund how to install. this `bower install --save locationProvider` did not work

Comment: are you sure you are using latest angularjs version? This should come with angular

Comment: I am using AngularJS v1.2.6 and installed it using the bower engine. I just saw a video where they configured a `server.js` file to redirect routes, is that the kind of thing I should be looking at. thank btw